# Difference between the meaning of "For this reason" and "in this regard"

Tags: meaning

Celebrities are increasingly becoming famous for their luxury lifestyle than their achievements. **For this reason,** they are bad role models for children.

Celebrities are increasingly becoming famous for their luxury lifestyle than their achievements. **In this regard,** they are bad role models for children.

Is there a difference in meaning or not?

Answer (score 1):

These samples will both be understood to mean that celebrities are bad role models, but the two phrases in bold, 'For this reason', and 'In this regard' don't mean exactly the same thing. So the two samples have slightly different meanings.

The first sample is less equivocal than the second. It says that they are bad examples and gives the reason. It doesn't suggest the possibility that there might be another way of looking at the situation.

The phrase 'in this regard', means something like

> from this perspective

Because there can be several perspectives on any situation, the second sample leaves the possibility open that there might be another way of looking at things. In another regard, celebrities might not be such bad role models.

> Celebrities give a lot of money to charity. In this regard, they are good role models for children.

The first sample could be given the same possibility that there's another perspective, but it would have to be made explicit.

> Celebrities are increasingly becoming famous more for their luxury lifestyle than their achievements. For this reason, they are bad role models for children. But because they give money to charity, they can be seen as good role models as well.

By the way, the first sentence in your samples is missing something. the word 'than' needs something to help compare 'luxury lifestyle' to achievements. There are two ways you could complete the sentence.

> Celebrities are increasingly becoming famous more for their luxury lifestyle than their achievements.
>   Celebrities are increasingly becoming famous for their luxury lifestyle rather than their achievements.